# Tranform Vega Lite into Vega

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop, vega, deneb

I would like to create a chart in Vega that concatenates three views. The idea is to use an outer 'hconcat' to combine an inner 'vconcat' of two charts—a line chart and a horizontal bar chart—on the left side. These two charts share a common x-axis but have independent y-axes. Additionally, I aim to include a third chart—a vertical bar chart—on the right side, which will have different x-axis and y-axis scales.

I can achieve this in Vega-Lite but haven't been able to find any references or examples for this specific layout in Vega. Can anyone help with identifying the workaround in VEGA?

Thank you!

Comment: Share your spec. Don't forget that VL transpiles to Vega and you can get the code from the editor.

Comment: Thanks, Davide! wish I knew this sooner! Will try on Monday and let you know.

Comment: oh yes...forgot to come back....I did what you suggested - put the Vega-Lite code into the editor and it generated the Vega code which I could use for this purpose :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you paste your VL code in the [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/), you can click the following button to see the transpiled Vega code.

[image]